# Invoice numbering in Rails + MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, invoices

I'd like to have organised invoices in this format:

```
AB20140001
```

`AB` is the acronym of our company, `20140001` is the first invoice in 2014.The current quick idea is to  add to the table `invoices` columns `year` and `invoice_number` and where would be stored `2014` and the current number of invoice (`0001` for the first one).

However, how to keep the column `invoice_number` in the format `XXXX` (for the second invoice would be the number `0002` and so on)?

Or - is there a better way to organise invoice numbering?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can do this in MySQL but you need a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do a function that runs after create and sets the serial number

We used `:after_create` so that we can use the `:id` after it was set.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :set_invoice_numeber

  def set_invoice_number
    self.update_attribute(:invoice_number, 'AB' + Time.now.year + '%.4d' % id)
  end

end
```

Comment: `id` will be set `after_create`, so he should use that. Also, I assume in 2015 he wants to start with `AB20150001`. Your answer does not provide a solution for that.

Comment: TypeError (no implicit conversion of Integer into String). Need convert to string for the year.So it will like `Time.now.year.to_s`